# Size in TCHARs is sizeof or _tcslen?

Tags: winapi

What means size in TCHARs from msdn?

For example:

> The size of the lpFilename buffer, in TCHARs.

If i have a buffer:

```
WCHAR buf[256];
```

So i need to pass 256, or 512? _tsclen(buf) or sizeof(buf)?

Comment: 256, _tsclen(buf), or can say sizeof(buf)/sizeof(TCHAR)

Comment: This is a case, where [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is helpful. Most Windows API calls use the `cch` prefix to specify the *Count of CHaracters*, while a `cb` prefix is used for the *Count of Bytes*. *"The size [...] in TCHARs"* is the same as the *count of characters*. In other words: Use `_tcslen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` is always in `char`s, which is equivalent to saying it's always in bytes.  `TCHAR`s are not necessarily `chars`, so `sizeof` is the wrong answer.

Using `tsclen(buf)` is correct **if** you want to pass the length (in `TCHAR`s) of the string in the buffer.  If you want to pass the length of the buffer itself, you can use `sizeof(buf)/sizeof(TCHAR)` or, more generally, `sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0])`.  Windows provides a macro called `ARRAYSIZE` to avoid typing out this common idiom.

**But** you can only do that if `buf` is actually the buffer and not a pointer to a buffer (otherwise `sizeof(buf)` gives you the size of a pointer, which is not what you need).

Some examples:

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
::GetWindowsDirectory(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]));  // OK
::GetWindowsDirectory(buffer, ARRAYSIZE(buffer));  // OK
::GetWindowsDirectory(buffer, _tcslen(buffer));  // Wrong!
::GetWindowsDirectory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));  // Wrong!

TCHAR message[64] = "Hello World!";
::TextOut(hdc, x, y, message, _tcslen(message));  // OK
::TextOut(hdc, x, y, message, sizeof(message));  // Wrong!
::TextOut(hdc, x, y, message, -1);  // OK, uses feature of TextOut

void MyFunction(TCHAR *buffer) {
  // This is wrong because buffer is just a pointer to the buffer, so
  // sizeof(buffer) gives the size of a pointer, not the size of the buffer.
  ::GetWindowsDirectory(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]));  // Wrong!

  // This is wrong because ARRAYSIZE (essentially) does what we wrote out
  // in the previous example.
  ::GetWindowsDirectory(buffer, ARRAYSIZE(buffer));  // Wrong!

  // There's no right way to do it here.  You need the caller to pass in the
  // size of the buffer along with the pointer.  Otherwise, you don't know
  // how big it actually is.
}
```

Comment: Read my question again. You are saying that tsclen(buf) if i want to pass length. I am asking: WHAT neccessary i want to pass: a length of the string, or a length of the buf. So what i need to do: tsclen(buf) or sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]) if it required to "

    The size of the lpFilename buffer, in TCHARs.
". ???

Comment: This is a good answer and Adrian does not need to read the question again.

Comment: There's also `_countof` - I'm not sure what the difference is between this and `ARRAYSIZE`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I believe the only difference is, that they produce different error messages when used on something that isn't an array. This is for C++. When compiling C code, their implementation is identical.